# select function returning -1 on Windows Phone platform

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock2

I am struggling with select function. The function works fine if I am passing just readfds and exceptfds parameter, but when i pass writefds parameter a select functions returns -1 and WSAGetLastError returns error code 10022 which states: "Some invalid argument was supplied".

This function is used in function that works in multiplatform project, and the only platform where this problem occurs is Windows Phone platform. On the rest platform there are no issues regarding this function.

```
int result = 0;


fd_set rset;
fd_set wset;
fd_set eset;

FD_ZERO(&rset);
FD_ZERO(&wset);
FD_ZERO(&eset);

for(int i = 0; i<events.size(); i++){
    if(read){
         FD_SET(events[i]->rfd, &rset);
         FD_SET(event[i]->rfd, &eset);
    }

    if(write){
         FD_SET(events[i]->rfd, &wset);
        FD_SET(event[i]->rfd, &eset);
    }
}

int number = event.size();
fd_set rset_copy = rset;
fd_set wset_copy = wset;
fd_set eset_copy = eset;
timeval t;
t.tv_sec = 0;
t.tv_usec = 0;

result = select(number, &rset_copy,&wset_copy,&eset_copy,&t);
```

**EDIT**

Corrected the name of passed timeval value from "tv" to "t".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeval` variable is named `t`, but you are passing another variable named `tv` to the last parameter of `select()`.  Per the [`select()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx):

> WSAEINVAL
>  
>   **The time-out value is not valid**, or all three descriptor parameters were null.

Also, if either `read` or `write` is false, DO NOT pass the corresponding `fd_set` to `select()`, pass NULL instead.

On a side note:

1. the first parameter of `select()` is ignored on Windows platforms (other platforms do use it), so just set it to 0.  You are not passing the correct value to it anyway.
2. there is no need to make a copy of the `fd_set` structs since they are local variables to begin with.
3. When `write` is true, are you sure that `->rfd` is the correct socket to store in `wset`? What is `event[i]` declared as exactly? Is there a `->wfd` field?

Try this instead:

```
if ((!events.empty()) && (read || write))
{
    int result = 0;

    fd_set rset, *prset = NULL;
    fd_set wset, *pwset = NULL;
    fd_set eset;

    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_ZERO(&wset);
    FD_ZERO(&eset);

    for(int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++)
    {
        if (read) FD_SET(events[i]->rfd, &rset);
        if (write) FD_SET(events[i]->rfd, &wset);
        FD_SET(event[i]->rfd, &eset);
    }

    if (read) prset = &rset;
    if (write) pwset = &wset;

    timeval t;
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    t.tv_usec = 0;

    result = select(0, prset, pwset, &eset, &t);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Events are internally implemented event handles for sockets. And they are working fine since they pass the tests. The rfd field is a SOCKET. And thank you very much for your answer! Setting a pointers to NULL and then setting just one of them to address of fd_set structure worked and it works like a charm right now. But I am still very curious why it worked for reading and didn't work for writing ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is but part of the whole code. I don't know if it would be different in visual c and Windows Phone but this may help.

In

```
result = select(number, &rset_copy,&wset_copy,&eset_copy,&tv);
```

You are passing &tv while you declare timeval t. This is a compile time error. I assume your code is different.

- Check that either read or write are greater than 0
- Are you sure absolutely all events[i]->rfd are valid file descriptors for sockets?
- Are you including Winsock2.h?
- try null instead of &t (or tv) for blocking select:

`result = select(number, &rset_copy,&wset_copy,&eset_copy,null);`

Comment: Michal is trying to call `select()` with a 0 millisecond timeout.  Using `null` instead will not do that, it will block until a socket is readable, writable, or in error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, you are correct. I Assume he is trying to block until a socket is readable, a write occurred, or an error occurred. Maybe not, in that case point 4 is not necessary